# How to user result from first query to second query

Tags: sql-server, database

I need to use result from first query to second query.

```
declare @categories tp_intList;
insert into @categories values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5);

select * from product AS prod
inner join 
(
    select MatchedCategoryId from MatchConfigCategories AS dd
    inner join @categories c on c.id = dd.maincategoryid
    inner join (select id from get_AllSubCategories(dd.MatchedCategoryId)) AS cats on prod.shopcatid = cats.id
) AS x on prod.ShopCatid = 4568
```

I need this to use to `get_AllSubCategories`. Parameter is `tp_intList` but i need here `matchedcategoryid` from `matchconfigcategories`. How can I do this?
I've got error something like this

> The multi-part identifier

Comment: Could you post some sample data and expected results?  Looking at your sample query, it's difficult to determine exactly what it is you are trying to accomplish.  Also, if you could post the entire error message and not just the first few words, it would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @cat tp_intList;
INSERT INTO @cat
select ...
```

this works fine for me